# What did I buy? non-Lego minifigures, in green

Tags: set-identification, minifigures, clone-brands

I bought this bag of figures today and have no clue what they are, or why I bought them for that matter.

12 "Men figurines", each individually wrapped.  Appears that they are all different.

Are they Lego?  Something else?

[image: figures]
[image: Figures]

Comment: They're not lego - a telltale sign is that lego minifigs don't have shoes as a separate piece. I cannot readily pinpoint the maker, though. Them being half green and half grey uniforms suggest they're part of some WW2 soldier pack.

Comment: I've gone through https://uploads.brickset.com/docs/clonebrands_v1.8.pdf , but I cannot see any (known) clone brand with a legs+shoes assembly like in your photo. Identifying the exact clone brand might be hard.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Another clear indication that they're not Lego is that they're modern era/WW2 soldiers, which is something that Lego refuses to produce toys of.

Answer (score 9):

These are from Wuhui ( or Wuhui mall)

- WUHUI 12PCS SWAT Military Army WW2 Minifigures Toy Building Kit [image]